# If I scroll up or down, my images are redownloading and changing positions

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I am getting image path from service and I am downloading from service and displaying in image view. My problem is if I scroll down or up Images are reloading and changing there positions.

```
 public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            Log.d("getview:", "position=" + position);
            View vi = convertView;
            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {

                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_asset_list_item, null);
                // vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_asset_list_item, parent,
                // false);

                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.tvGroupTitle = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tvGroupTitle);
                holder.tvGroupDescription = (TextView) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.tvGroupDescription);
                holder.imgscrollchild = (LinearLayout) vi
                        .findViewById(R.id.imgscrollchild);

                vi.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
            }
            if (data.size() <= 0) {

                vi.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } else {

                tempValues = null;
                tempValues = (GroupsModel) data.get(position);
                for (int k = 0; k < data.size(); k++) {

                }
                holder.tvGroupTitle.setText(tempValues.getName().toString());
                holder.tvGroupDescription.setText(tempValues.getDescription().toString());
                holder.imgscrollchild.removeAllViews();


                if (tempValues.getItemmodel().size() == 0) {
                    return vi;
                } else {

                    for (int i = 0; i < tempValues.getItemmodel().size(); i++) {
                        a = i;
                        Log.i("Index", String.valueOf(i));

                        holder.imgscrollchild.addView(createimg(tempValues.getItemmodel(), a));
                        Log.i("Index A", String.valueOf(a));

                    }

                }

            }
            return vi;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Scrollview instead of listview. e.g.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutLoadData"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

- in java file.

  ```
  LinearLayout layoutLoadData=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutLoadData);


  for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {

      View view = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
      layoutLoadData.addView(view);
  }
  ```